# Problem with Expanding and shrinking Table on load

Tags: javascript, html

I am revising the code to better match the HTML table that mplungjan created below. However I am keeping the FOR loops as this is how I am generating the tables.

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th style="text-align:center">Expand</th>
    </thead>
    
    {% for supply in supplylist %}
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td data-toggle="toggle">
                    <p><a href="#" class="plusminusexpands" size="large">+</a></p>
                </td>
```

**Here is problem I am trying to solve:**

When clicking the link above, I want to write either a + or - to this variable below **supply[0]**

When loading the form, I want to read the value from this same variable and either shrink or expand the specific row based on whether its value is '+' or '-'

Is there a Java Script that I can use to read this variable on load and either shrink or expand the row as applicable.

And is there a Java Script that I can use to write either a + or - to this variable whenever the user clicks the link.

```
                <td style="display:none"><input name="expand" value="{{supply[0]}}"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
            
        <tbody class="hideTr">
            {% for number in supply[5] %}
                <tr>
                    <td>To be hidden {{number}}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>To be hidden</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>To be hidden</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>    
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

I am revising the Script to use mplungjan's example below as well, since this script also works and is more modern.

```
<script>
    const toggleTbody = function() {
        const $tbodyToToggle = $(this).closest('tbody').next(".hideTr");
        $tbodyToToggle.toggle()
        const visible = $tbodyToToggle.is(":visible")
        $(this).text(visible ? '-' : '+')
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.plusminusexpands')
        .on('click',toggleTbody)
        .each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() === "+") $(this).click()
        })
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is this at all a python issue? If not, please click [edit], then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] with ONLY RENDERED HTML and JavaScript. No need to post any Python. Please render 3 rows of your table so we can test the script

Comment: @mplungjan: My project is a Python/Flask Project so it is intrinsically related to this issue, but this issue is likely just a Javascript issues that I have.

Comment: @mplungjan: I updated the tags and title. I am comfortable with Python and Flask, not great with HTML, and got no skill of JS or JQuery. I use the <tbody> tag to identify the section of code that I want to shrink or expand. In my actual code, I have a new table within the row here, but that is not relevant to this question. My code may be ancient but its at least working for now.

Comment: You are correct about the JS.Anchors. The original code was only changing the .text() value from either + to - or vice versa. Instead of that, I want to be able to change the value of the variable stored in the specific row. I also noticed that the this particular script was changing all the texts in that that column regardless of table row, which was not what I wanted at all.

Comment: I was able to add a link to show what my final output looks like at the bottom of the post. Its using different HTML than what I wrote above to create the tables, but the core issue is the same.

Comment: @mplungjan I didn't ignore your request, you simply do not understand what I am asking for. I will think on this and revise my request.

Comment: No offense. Thank you for trying to address my question. I agree, I didn't do a good job communicating the problem I am having. I'm very new to HTML and JS, so its difficult for me to detail the specific problem I am having.

Answer (score 0):

Lacking the expected example HTML, I produced my own

- I added a tbody to the toggle rows
- You can now set the plus or minus on the server and I use localStorage to not have to store the settings in a session
- IDs need to be unique so I removed the ID and just use the class

Here is a version with localStorage - I use try/catch to run on SO because localStorage is sandboxed

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const $plusMinuses = $('.plusminusexpands'); // all the plusminusexpands
  let savedPlusMinuses; // this will be the array we use
  try { // stacksnippets do not like localStorage
    savedPlusMinuses = localStorage.getItem("savedPlusMinuses");
    savedPlusMinuses = savedPlusMinuses ? JSON.parse(savedPlusMinuses) : [];
  }
  catch {
    console.log("no localStorage available");
    savedPlusMinuses = []; // set to empty array
  }
  // here we gather default values in case of first visit
  if (savedPlusMinuses.length === 0) savedPlusMinuses = $plusMinuses.map(function() {
    return this.textContent.trim()
  }).get(); // get the current set of plusminus
  

  const toggleTbody = function() {
    const $tbodyToToggle = $(this).closest('tbody').next(".hideTr");
    $tbodyToToggle.toggle()
    const visible = $tbodyToToggle.is(":visible")
    $(this).text(visible ? '-' : '+')
    savedPlusMinuses[$(this).data("idx")] = $(this).text()
    console.log(savedPlusMinuses.join("")); // debugging
    // localStorage.setItem("savedPlusMinuses",JSON.stringify(savedPlusMinuses)); // uncomment
  };

  // set the event handler on the plusminues and then loop to initialise the DOM
  $plusMinuses
    .on('click', toggleTbody)
    .each(function(i) { // looping all the plus/minuses to set the state
      $(this).text(savedPlusMinuses[i]) // initialise with saved values
        .data("idx", i); // set a data-attribute to find it quickly when saving
      if ($(this).text() === "+") $(this).click()
    })
});
```

```css
.plusminusexpands {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: x-large
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th style="text-align:center">Expand</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-toggle="toggle">
        <p><a href="#" class="plusminusexpands">+</a></p>
      </td>
      <td style="display:none"><input name="expand" value="{{supply[0]}}"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="hideTr">
    <tr>
      <td>To be hidden 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>To be hidden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>To be hidden</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-toggle="toggle">
        <p><a href="#" class="plusminusexpands">-</a></p>
      </td>
      <td style="display:none"><input name="expand" value="{{supply[0]}}"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="hideTr">
    <tr>
      <td>To be hidden 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>To be hidden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>To be hidden</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-toggle="toggle">
        <p><a href="#" class="plusminusexpands">+</a></p>
      </td>
      <td style="display:none"><input name="expand" value="{{supply[0]}}"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="hideTr">
    <tr>
      <td>To be hidden 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>To be hidden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>To be hidden</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is a version which would need to save the plusminusses using Ajax to the server

```js
const toggleTbody = function() {
    const $tbodyToToggle = $(this).closest('tbody').next(".hideTr");
    $tbodyToToggle.toggle()
    const visible = $tbodyToToggle.is(":visible")
    $(this).text(visible ? '-' : '+')
  }
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.plusminusexpands')
    .on('click',toggleTbody)
    .each(function() { // looping all the plus/minuses to set the state
      if ($(this).text() === "+") $(this).click()
    })
});
```

```css
.plusminusexpands { text-decoration:none; font-size: x-large }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <th style="text-align:center">Expand</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-toggle="toggle">
        <p><a href="#" class="plusminusexpands" size="large">+</a></p>
      </td>
      <td style="display:none"><input name="expand" value="{{supply[0]}}"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="hideTr">
    <tr>
      <td>To be hidden 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>To be hidden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>To be hidden</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-toggle="toggle">
        <p><a href="#" class="plusminusexpands" size="large">-</a></p>
      </td>
      <td style="display:none"><input name="expand" value="{{supply[0]}}"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="hideTr">
    <tr>
      <td>To be hidden 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>To be hidden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>To be hidden</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-toggle="toggle">
        <p><a href="#" class="plusminusexpands" size="large">+</a></p>
      </td>
      <td style="display:none"><input name="expand" value="{{supply[0]}}"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody class="hideTr">
    <tr>
      <td>To be hidden 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>To be hidden</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>To be hidden</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I do have some nested loops in my table, but that's actually not the problem. Your code above is similar to mine, but I think its more modern. Either way, the issue I am having is in remembering which row was expanded when loading the form. I am trying write to a variable "supply[0]" either a + or a - depending on whether that row was expanded or shrunk. And upon load, I want to check the value of that variable to determine which row needs to be expanded or shrunk. That's the code I need help with. The Supply[0] variable is part of the first For loop that I am using the generate the table].

Comment: I will look into Local Storage. I just got a book on Java Script and JQuery, so maybe It will help.

Comment: You are right...I just noticed that if it starts with a +, it will shrink the row, and if it starts with a - it will expand it accordingly. This just leaves me with the problem of recording the current assignment each time the link is clicked. That is brilliant mplungjan!

Comment: See updated answer where the first script will use localStorage. You will have to uncomment the lines with localStorage on your server

Comment: That code works perfectly! Only thing is I have no idea how it works. LOL. Thank you for the comments. I'm going to have to read up on this to better understand it.

Comment: I gave plenty of comments I believe

Comment: You did and I appreciate it. I apologize earlier for being defensive. I think I understand the point you were making now. In my head I was only focused on the answer I was looking for. And because of that I didn’t produce usable or even testable code here. You ended up giving me a workaround for my problem, making my entire approach unnecessary. An approach I never would have used because of how little I know of all this. I just need to actually spend the time to digure it all out now. Thank you.